# UIPageViewController title scrolling

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller, uinavigationitem

In my app i'm using UIPageViewController with scrolling transition style. Everything works fine but I'm wondering if there is a way to scroll navigation item title alongside with controller? Now i'm only able to change title after new controller is shown in method:

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [AnyObject], transitionCompleted completed: Bool)
```

Comment: Interesting idea. Don't know whether it looks so nice when the title scrolls over other items in the navigation bar, e.g. back button or other buttons.

Comment: I also want title to fade out ;)